# Phonegap iOS app performance is very poor while AJAX Request is frequently use

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am developing phonegap application in iOS using cordova3.5.0. In my application I want to update data every minute. I am using Ajax request for that. Every minute, Ajax request is initiated and response is coming from server.

I have observed that performance of the application is very poor on iPhone 5s iOS 8 (new device) and as well as on iPhone 4 iOS 7 (older device).

I cannot figure out any reason why the application performance is so poor on the newer device also. I have observed that when Ajax request is initiated, then the response from the server is delayed for 30 seconds. I cannot figure out that why response is delayed. Is it due to Phonegap environment or else?

I have also observed this in browser, server response is very fast and in core android application is also the server response is very fast. If anyone can guide me then it will be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Comment: show what have you done here.

Comment: pardon @Dato'MohammadNurdin, I didn't understand your comment. Its a simple ajax request initiated every one minute.

Comment: you have to post some code snippet(s) so that we can understand the issue better